# Duplicating Opera icon in Gnome Shell Dash

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

When I launch Opera manually I have a [single icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rZWD.png) in the Dash (red icon on top). But when restarting Gnome Shell (with Opera running) or having Opera restored from saved session on login, another Opera icon [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0nJ1.png) (see the bottom icon) which looks slightly different from the first one.

I don't have any idea why it happens or what I need to do to help you locate the problem, so any advice is appreciated.

I'm running RFRemix, a Fedora-based Linux distribution, and have Opera installed from a RFRemix repo.

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks for the response, but I didn't find any corresponding lines it these files.